# "Site cannot be reached" Socket.IO

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have been trying to connect `54.255.140.142:3000` using Socket.IO.

I tried to open port using `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT` command.

It's giving error as "Site cannot be reached"

Comment: can you ping it? `ping 54.255.140.142`

Comment: Not getting any response. Does that mean anything? My site is running fine though 54.255.140.142

Comment: do you have nmap? if you `nmap 54.255.140.142`, it will tell you which ports your server has open. However, if you can't even ping the server and get a response, that's a problem

Comment: @delboy1978uk getting this error "From 172.29.181.99 icmp_seq=800 Destination Host Unreachable" after a while.

Comment: eh? why the different IP?

Comment: I am sorry that's hostname and host IP is 172.29.181.99. I tried ping 172.29.181.99 and got response. On nmap 172.29.181.99 i got

Not shown: 991 closed ports
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
135/tcp   open     msrpc
445/tcp   open     microsoft-ds
514/tcp   filtered shell
543/tcp   filtered klogin
902/tcp   open     iss-realsecure
912/tcp   open     apex-mesh
2701/tcp  open     sms-rcinfo
5002/tcp  filtered rfe
27352/tcp filtered unknown

Comment: an IP is not a hostname! Okay, and it looks like that server is not listening on port 3000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182346/discussion-between-user3610877-and-delboy1978uk).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port 3000 is open or closed.